# Cloud Service Startup Tasks: Add domain user

Tags: batch-file, cmd, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-vm-role

I would like to add domain\user to Cloud Service WebRole / VM during startup tasks. I have ExpressRoute enable for my subscription and I have configured ILB endpoint to my webrole. I am running following startup task to make VM to join domain and add domain users.

1. ConfigureDnsPrefixes
2. EnableRemoteDesktop
3. JoinDomain
4. CreateLocalAdmin (failing)

CreateLocalAdmin.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF 

IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\" MKDIR "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog"

IF "%EMULATED%"=="true" (
    ECHO Running emulated >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1
) ELSE (
    ECHO Add current user to administrators group >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1
    net localgroup "Administrators" %computername%\%username% /add >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1

    ECHO Add domain user to "Administrators" and "Remote Desktop Users" security groups >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1
    net localgroup "Administrators" USERNAME_SETTING /add >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1
    net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" USERNAME_SETTING /add >> "%TEMP%\StartupTasksLog\CreateLocalAdmin.txt" 2>&1
)

EXIT /B 0
```

I tried manually login to VM and add domain\user. System asked domain\user, password to add that user. I am not sure how do I perform this task during startup. I am adding current user to local administrators group first so system can perform task based as local admin.